# How to change IBM-Cloud cloudfoundry golang app version?

Tags: go, ibm-cloud

When I run command `ibmcloud target --cf && ibmcloud cf restart appname`, it showed an error, it seems like golang version is invalid, but I can't change it to specify version without root permission, or can it be an old version by creating container for instance?

```
   Downloading app package...
   Downloaded app package (20.8K)
   -----> Go Buildpack version 1.9.16
          **WARNING** [DEPRECATION WARNING]:
          **WARNING** Please use AppDynamics extension buildpack for Golang Application instrumentation
          **WARNING** for more details: https://docs.pivotal.io/partners/appdynamics/multibuildpack.html
   -----> Checking Godeps/Godeps.json file
   -----> Installing godep 80
          Download [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/godep/godep-v80-linux-x64-cflinuxfs3-b60ac947.tgz]
   -----> Installing glide 0.13.3
          Download [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/glide/glide-v0.13.3-linux-x64-cflinuxfs3-ef07acb5.tgz]
   -----> Installing dep 0.5.4
          Download [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/dep/dep-v0.5.4-linux-x64-cflinuxfs3-79b3ab9e.tgz]
          **ERROR** Unable to determine Go version to install: no match found for 1.11.x in [1.13.14 1.13.15 1.14.6 1.14.7]
   Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run all supply scripts: exit status 16
   Exit status 223
   Cell e0f8b881-1ded-45a7-a004-101d32dc7f6d stopping instance 3d1adec5-7f49-47a1-8005-e25e83521422
   Cell e0f8b881-1ded-45a7-a004-101d32dc7f6d destroying container for instance 3d1adec5-7f49-47a1-8005-e25e83521422
Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your environment is configured for an older Golang version. And the version was not found in the installed, available buildpacks. You could either look into your manifest and other config files what version is set. Or you could switch to a different buildpack by using the [manifest attribute](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#buildpack) or  a command option (see `ibmcloud cf push --help` to list the buildpack option).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify Go version in the manifest.yml file like this

```
---
applications:
  - name: my-app-name
    env:
      GOVERSION: go1.8
```

Supported Go versions can be found in the [release notes](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/go-buildpack/releases).

Also, refer [getting started with GO](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry?topic=cloud-foundry-getting-started-go) guide to understand how to work with GO app on Cloud Foundry

Comment: Glad it worked. Can you mark this as an answer so that it helps others who are facing a similar issue :)